How can I identify the encoding of this encrypted .mp4?
I want to know the encoding of an encrypted .mp4 used in a video game. It plays within the game on Windows but not on Wine/Proton, and I want to figure out how to get it to run on Wine/Proton. Here is the video: https://mega.nz/file/BihXDAqZ#IbvATL-x9LuKByYz_XtJUblSXncR2GbHG2lLLNM9Vw4
I have tried to use MediaInfo and FFprobe, but have not been successful. MediaInfo does not recognise it as a video file and FFprobe gives the following error:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x623896dceb80] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x623896dceb80] moov atom not found
JReastTrainSimulator_OP.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Welcome to Superuser. I don't know that this question will fit well here. We don't really like downloading random files from web sources, for one. For another, the game devs have a wide variety of tools to obfuscate or conceal this file, and encryption is only one of them.


please remove the link from your question. it almost certianly contains copyrighted material.
what does the encoding of the underlying video have to do with the real problem (that its encrypted)? the game is going to try to decrypt the video at runtime, and will continue to do that, even if you gave it an unencrypted video file (which would result in gibberish) so even if you removed the DRM from the file, you would have to alter game code as well.


@FrankThomas The file is of the game's intro video; I find it unlikely that there will be objections to sharing it. Second, my intention is that since the game successfully decrypts the video at runtime on Windows, but not on Wine/Proton, learning something about the encryption would help in discovering why the game is failing to decrypt the video on Wine/Proton.

what do you mean by "the encoding"? Do you mean the video/audio codecs? If so, simply decrypt the mp4, then mediaInfo and ffprobe will be able to give that to you

What makes you think the file is encrypted instead of simply encoded with an encoding that WINE/Proton doesn’t support

@Bravo I can't decrypt the file as stated. When I say "the encoding", I mean in effective terms both the encoding and possible encryption.

@Ramhound From memory, the file also does not play in standard Windows media players. As stated, both MediaInfo and FFprobe failed to help me identify the encoding and/or encryption.

@eldomtom2 - regardless of what you meant by your usage of the word encoding,  IF the file is indeed encrypted, you'll need to decrypt it before you can do anything else. And since you can't decrypt it, as stated, then you have no way to proceed.

FWIW, Virustotal shows that file as "clean".   When I downloaded it to my Linux system it identifies as having a file type of ".com" - ie a DOS executable.  That said, I doubt it is a .com file as its larger then 64k - I expect its just a binary blob - certainly it does not appear to have any meaningful signature.  (COM files apparently don't have any signature).  I do wonder if its some kind of bespoke encrypted file format which requires widevine - and which I suspect WINE does not support.

@davidgo How would I identify if it is a bespoke encrypted file format? As a note, the only "DRM", if such is present, appears to be restricted to ensuring the video is only playable by the game.

So what DRM is used? Only specific DRM is weak enough to be broken.

Its likely not possible to identify the encrypted file format without disassembling whatever is playing it. Well past my paygrade.
